# How to create string of strings in c++

Tags: c++, string

I want to have sometnig like this:

- first   second   first    second
- third   first    second   first
- thirst  asdfasd  adfads   asdfadf
- sdfsdf  sdfasdf  afdsdf   dffsd

It has 4 rows and 4 columns. *Each row, column pair is a string.*

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask a question. What have you tried so far? Nobody here is going to hold your hand and write all your code for you.

Comment: Explain the problem and leave others to understand the problem.

Comment: Wow. Clear. Precise. To the point.

Comment: the answer is `string magic[4][4]` . I feel it.

Answer (score 1):

A *string of strings* is different than a *table* or *matrix* of strings.

**String of Strings**
Let a string be one or more sequential characters, such as `"first"`.
A string may contain another string or commonly known as a *substring*.  The string `"theater"` contains at least the strings `"the"`, `"eat"`, and `"ate"`.

**Matrix of Strings**
A matrix of strings contains rows and columns of strings:

```
"first"    "second"  "apple"  "car"  
"garden"   "table"   "pear"   "tire"  
"hero"     "cat"     "orange" "window"  
"soil"     "food"    "mango"  "engine"
```

A matrix of strings can be declared as:

```
std::string  string_matrix[4][4];
```

Other data structures can be used to represent a matrix of strings, such as linked lists.